# Taking the value on didSelectItemAt for indexPath and add it to a delegate / protocol to populate a header cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, protocols

Using protocol / delegate & retrieve the data from didSelectItemAt (collectionViews).

```
// This class have the data 
// WhereDataIs: UICollectionViewController
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //Pass some data from the didSelect to a delegate

        let test = things[indexPath.item]
        guard let bingo = test.aThing else { return }
        print("bingo: ", bingo)
```

That bingo is printing the value that I need. So pretty good right there.

Now, I can't use the method of the protocol inside of that function, that's bad execution so the compiler or Xcode says hey, you will declare the method as a regular method, not the nested way.

```
//Bridge
protocol xDelegate {
    func x(for headerCell: HeaderCell)
}
```

```
//This is the class that need the data
//class HeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell
var xDelegate: xDelegate?

//it's init()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let sally = WhereDataIs()
        self.xDelegate = sally

        xDelegate?.x(for: self)
}
```

```
// This extension is added at the end of the class WhereDataIs()
// Inside of this class is it's delegate.

var xDelegate: xDelegate? = nil

extension WhereDataIs: xDelegate {
    func x(for headerCell: HeaderCell) {
        //Smith value will work because it's dummy
        headerCell.lbl.text = "Smith"

       // What I really need is instead of "Smith" is the value of didselectItemAt called bingo.
headerCell.lbl.text = bingo
    }
}
```

Hat's off for anyone who would like to guide me in this.

Comment: You are discouraged from manipulating a cell in `didSelectRow`. The next time the user scrolls the value will be reverted. Update the model and reload the row or section.

Comment: Thanks, what you are saying is that I need to pass the data to the parent of that cell which will be the item clicked... but I got a problem right there, cuz I'm just adding a collectionView as a view, not pushing through any NavBar nor Modal. 'm doing this programatically not using IB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not using delegates, but it will work**

Solved by:

1) go to the controller of the collectionView. make a new variable to store the items.

```
// Pass the item object into the xController so that it can be accessed later. 
//(didSelectItemAt)
 xController.newVar = item 

//xController class: UICollectionView... 
// MARK: - Properties 
var newVar: Thing?
```

Finally in that class, you should have the the method **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind** in which you register the HeaderCell and then just add...

```
let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

header.lbl.text = newVar.whatEverYourDataIs
```

**Little generic but it works. :)**

Comment: awesome thank you very much and have a beautiful day (:

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add this to the end of your current code in `didSelectItemAt indexPath`:

```
guard let header = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: "yourElementKind", at: indexPath) as? HeaderCell else { return }

header.lbl.text = bingo

collectionView.reloadData()
```

*Edit:* Keep everything else for now to ensure you get a good result first.

Let me know if this works, happy to check back.

Comment: First, I had a brain fart and now realized you're looking to update the header instead of the cell you're tapping. Also there is more than I believed was going on, so updating my post accordingly now. If it still doesn't work, feel free to PM me or link a git repo.

Comment: Same behaviour, itsn't opening the new screen.

Thanks for the update, using the breakpoints, header.lbl.text = bingo isn't hitting as well as before with the cellForRowAt, any thoughts over there?

the placeholder forElementKind is: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader

Comment: Hmm I'm stumped for now, would be curious to see your project to know what else is going on and expected!

Comment: adding the code to the end of the didSelectItemAt will open the new window but without hitting the header.lbl.text = bingo.

Comment: Unfortunately I would need to check out the code to help further. Best of luck otherwise!